# Textarea with GO button (submit) on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, textarea, submit

I have a form with a textarea (it's a chat).
Pressing enter submits the form (via javascript/jquery)

It works beautifully on all regular computers with an enter key. But on iPhone, there is no enter key, and the GO (submit) button does not appear, meaning the form can't be sent

No problem if the textarea was instead **input type="text"** field, but then I miss the multi-line wrapping etc. from a textarea

How do I work around this? I would rather not show a submit button nor make two versions of the form.
And I believe an input field can't behave as a textarea, right? (multiline)

Comment: Have you considered adding a submit button? You cover yourself from all directions if you did that.

Comment: `I would rather not show a submit button nor make two versions of the form. `

Comment: @Jenox: It doesn't rule away my point. It's good practice to have a submit button to every form, just in case it's not obvious that you need to use an enter key.

Comment: Yeah I have considered it. And for now I settle with some simple browser sniffing, to show the button to iPhone users (should include all devices that hides the GO button), but I'm looking for some solution to not show the button ;)

Comment: @mowgli: Quick question, why do you need multiline in chat? And how are you planning to using it?

Comment: @Truth it's just so that people can type/paste longer text if they want to (and still have some overview of the text). And so I can keep the chatwindow small.. but maybe I should try and work around a regular input field. That would solve it I guess..

Comment: @Truth I would like that idea too, but mowgli said he does not want it and was very strict with my answer...

Comment: @mowgli: Regular text fields do not allow for newlines, and I **still** don't understand why you don't want the button!.

Comment: @Truth One huge reason for not having the submitbutton, is to signal "you don't have to fetch the mouse/whatever and click anything. just stay at the keyboard and press enter" ;)

Comment: @Jenox What idea do you mean, where did you suggest it, and where was I strict? ;)

Comment: LOL. I told you how to use the return key as an 'enter button' and you downvoted because you wanted it to show a different text, which is simply not possible.

Comment: In my question I say "Pressing enter submits the form (via javascript/jquery)". You could have explained why you suggested a jquery function that does excactly that, instead of just "try this". And I don't want it to show a different text. Stop trolling now ;)

Comment: The suggestion to add an input button ignores the fact that the device will pop up an on screen keyboard which covers the form.